# Return from CustomAdapter to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listview

I want to return from my `CustomAdapter` that implements `ListAdapter` to the `MAinActivity`. The problem appears cause, this adapter was created from a fragment contained by the `MainActivity`. I tried to pass the activity through the constructor of the adapter with:

```
CustomAdapaterListaServicios customAdapter = new CustomAdapaterListaServicios (ArrayList, getContext (), (Main Activity) getActivity ());    
ListaServicios. setAdapter (customAdapter);
```

What I tried passing as parameter the activity is to access a method on `MainActivity` to display the fragment desired, but doesn't work. This return to the fragment container of `MainActivity` is started by clicking a button on the `CustomAdapter` in the method `getView(...)`.

The `MainActivity` to change between fragments use this line:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragmentTag)
            .commit();
```

The fragment that contains the `ListView` find the `listView` and starts the `customAdapter` as I showed before.

The goal is to return to the `MainActivity` by clicking the button contained on the row of the `ListView` and show the fragment desired.

Comment: why are you trying to pass the adapter, instead of the data it contains ?

Comment: why can't you create the customer adapter in another activity?

Comment: I only showed how I set the adapter on the ListView contained by the fragment. The arrayList contains the data @a_local_nobody

Comment: i understand, but why are you trying to pass around an adapter ? why can't you recreate it with the same data

Comment: I'm saying that you are stuck on a solution you're trying to implement, and not the problem you're trying to solve :) try explaining *what* you're trying to achieve as well as *how* you've tried doing, then it will probably be easier for people to help you